# How to redirect to a View of another Controller from one Controller's View in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating  a Login page, where there'll be two buttons. One is submit type 'Sign-in' button and other is a redirecting button 'Sign-up' which gets the URL of a view of another controller.
This **login** page (View) belongs to **Login** Controller and the redirecting button should access the **MemberSignup** View of the **SignUp** Controller.

```
    <p>
     <input type="button" value="Sign Up" class="btn" onclick= "document.location.href='SignUp/MemberSignUp'";/>
   </p>
```

while running the above code it is executing with the URL: ~/Login/SignUp/MemberSignUp. Thus giving an error as the Login controller should not be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as [ActionLink](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_htmlhelpers.asp) as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "MemberSignUp", "SignUp", null, new { @class="your-class" } })
```

Comment: are you using razor ? @SameepBaxi

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach if you don't want to rely on JavaScript for links on buttons, you can simply use an anchor and style it, making it look like a button, using css.

```
<a href="/Controller/View" class="Button">Your button text</a>
```

Comment: it is an hyperlink not a button. I need a button that would redirect after onclick action.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "/" before your url to indicate that the path is absolute, not relative : document.location.href='/SignUp/MemberSignUp'

Or use the razor method to generate the url (best method) : @Url.Action("MemberSignup", "SignUp");

Answer (score 0):

One method is just to point to the correct URL, example below;

```
<p>
   <a href="/SignUp/MemberSignUp" >Sign Up</a>
<p>
```

or as mentioned below you can use an ActionResult.

However the issue you're having with your code is that you're missing the leading / from your redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following helper method to your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text here", "MemberSignUp", "SignUp")
```

Moreover if you want some styling you can type:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text here", "MemberSignUp", "SignUp", null, new{ @class="your-class" })
```